# Azure blob storage - Dynamic routes / wild card

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a file in azure blob storage under the path /projects/project.html

How can i redirect (using blob storage) any projects/* path to this file in azure blob storage? this is a feature offered by most CDNs?

I.E i want someone routing /projects/123 to be delivered the /projects/project.html page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this directly with blob storage (and blob storage is not a CDN). You can either use something like an actual CDN (e.g. [Azure CDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-create-a-storage-account-with-cdn)) or also [Function Proxies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies) should work for your case.